# Использует ли SearchControl API геокодирования?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Доброе время суток, подскажите пожалуйста, используется ли API прямого геокодирования при поисковых запросах через SearchControl компонент яндекс карт?

Comment: Вопрос про то, является ли этот запрос тарифицируемым? Учитывается ли он в лимит 25000 в день?

Comment: Да, именно с этой целью и инетересуюсь. Ну по факту, у меня задача, заключающаяся в том, что бы заменить дефолтный поиск по карте, на свой кастомный, который будет включать в себя и яндекс поиск (я хочу попытаться использовать просто прямое геокодирование для сохранения функционала яндекс поиска). И тут, тоже, ещё один вопрос, не противоречит ли это условиям использования яндекс карт ?

Comment: Да, учитывается. Использование геокодирования без сохранения результатов не нарушает условия.

Comment: Спасибо большое :)